# Which algorithm is implemented in sklearn's SVM method?

Tags: svm, scikit-learn, libsvm

I'd like to know which exact version of svm is implemented in slearn. The [references](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html) section on sklearn's svm page cites [libsvm](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/papers/libsvm.pdf) package and a [paper](http://citeseer.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.41.1639) from 1999 which is about comparing classification error rate and likelihood scores. The libsvm paper talks about the original svm paper by Vapnik. But I couldn't figure out which exact formulation of svm has been implemented.

The libsvm paper cites a paper titled [Fast Training of Support Vector Machines Using Sequential Minimal Optimization](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/publication/fast-training-of-support-vector-machines-using-sequential-minimal-optimization/) that solves svm using a method called sequential minimal optimization. Is this the algorithm that sklearn actually calls under the hood or is it a different version of this method?

Answer (score 2):

Yes - the implementation there is based on libsvm - which does indeed implement Platt's SMO - you can see the details [in this paper](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/papers/libsvm.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

As you noticed, the documentation says it uses LibSVM, but if in doubt, check [the source code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/36958fb24/sklearn/svm/_classes.py#L525):

```py
class SVC(BaseSVC):
    """C-Support Vector Classification.
    The implementation is based on libsvm. The fit time scales at least
    [...]
```

which inherits from

```py
class BaseSVC(ClassifierMixin, BaseLibSVM, metaclass=ABCMeta):
    """ABC for LibSVM-based classifiers."""

    [...]
```

that inherits from

```py
class BaseLibSVM(BaseEstimator, metaclass=ABCMeta):
    """Base class for estimators that use libsvm as backing library.
    This implements support vector machine classification and regression.
    [...]
```

and [here we can find](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/36958fb240fbe435673a9e3c52e769f01f36bec0/sklearn/svm/_base.py#L251) the `fit` method

```py
    def fit(self, X, y, sample_weight=None):
        [...]
        fit = self._sparse_fit if self._sparse else self._dense_fit
        if self.verbose:
            print("[LibSVM]", end="")

        seed = rnd.randint(np.iinfo("i").max)
        fit(X, y, sample_weight, solver_type, kernel, random_seed=seed)
        [...]
```

which uses

```py
    def _dense_fit(self, X, y, sample_weight, solver_type, kernel, random_seed):
        [...]
            self.fit_status_,
            self._num_iter,
        ) = libsvm.fit(
            X,
            y,
        [...]
```

or

```py
    def _sparse_fit(self, X, y, sample_weight, solver_type, kernel, random_seed):
        [...]
            self.fit_status_,
            self._num_iter,
        ) = libsvm_sparse.libsvm_sparse_train(
            X.shape[1],
            X.data,
        [...]
```